# Changing to remote branch before pushing local commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I have committed some changes in master branch but **not** yet pushed to remote.
If I now switch to another remote branch (and run a git pull) I will not have any issue right?

Answer (score 1):

You will not. This is how distributed version control systems work. Read more about it here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control